# Issues running multiple bat files that set up environment from windows service where final bat file executes python script

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-services

I have a python script (app) that runs great when executed from a bat file. i.e. the bat file calls python and executes the py file. Before this executing it first prepares the paths and environments from some third party apps (like calling Anaconda activate and others). When I trigger this bat file from the command prompt or double clicking on it, all is well, each internal bat file is executed in sequence finally calling the python file.

However I have now set this up as a windows service. Using C# to call the bat file:
[how to create an installer for a .net windows service](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-net-windows-service.html)

I see that the bat file is being executed (as I print out to file to show it was triggered), the windows service starts and runs and even polls every 5 minutes and prints to windows event viewer.

All the bat files are executed (I have added prints to file in all of them) to ensure they are called and the py file is executed but fails.

What I have diagnosed is that as the call was done from windows service the individual bat files are almost executed in their own memory, similar to multi-processing in Python (I suspect). This means that as each bat file is executed it "doesn't see" the execution of the previous bat file so all environment variable and other settings are lost.

So when the py file is executed the settings that are required to preload are not loaded and it fails.

I have gone so far as to copy all the steps in each bat file and concatenate into one long bat file. But as there are some calls to 3rd party software like exe files for example it doesn't help, the work of the exe for example (I suspect) are loaded in own memory (my interpretation) and therefore same issue occurs, the required preload is not seen by the py.

As a simple example, there is a bat file call that calls Anaconda activate myEnvironment before other bat files are called. I see from the printout in the file that this was executed successfully but when the next bat file is called it doesn't see the execution of the previous (so doesn't continue to next step which uses the activated environment).

Again, when I load the bat file manually or through double click, all is well.

Has anyone had any experience in this?

Comment: Given that this is a programming code help site, is there a particular reason why you've decided not to submit any of the batch files, the python code, or in fact, the reason for tryung to run an application as a service?